# an unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to run the app but it showing 2 errors. The red line is under Label1.Txt and Label2.Txt. Refer to the following code

```
        public object Label1 { get; private set; }
        public object Label2 { get; private set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var username = HttpContext.Current.Session["username"];

            if (username == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
            }    
        }

        protected void submitt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {   con.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into [Students] values ('" + ID.Text + "','" + FN.Text + "', '" + LN.Text + "', '" + Country1.Text + "', '" + gender.SelectedValue + "',  '" + email.Text + "', '" + passportNo.Text + "', '" + PlaceOfIssue.Text + "', '" + issue.Text + "',  '" + Expiry.Text + "', '" + VisaNo.Text + "', '" + VisaExpiry.Text + "', '" + EmiratesNo.Text + "', '" + EmiaratesExpiry.Text + "');", con);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                Label1.Text = "Uploaded Successfully"; 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label2.Text = "Same data cannot be submitted again"; 
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Has "text" been declared for the two labels?

Comment: are you using web form?

Comment: yes i am using web forms, the text will be shown on submit button request only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change this

```
  public object Label1 { get; private set; }
  public object Label2 { get; private set; }
```

to this:

```
  public string Label1 { get; private set; }
  public string Label2 { get; private set; }
```

but this just will fix the exception and will not display message..

if you want to display message in label then you need to declare label in HTML like:

```
  <asp:label id="Label1" runat="server" />
  <asp:label id="Label2" runat="server" />
```

and then change your code to this:

```
    protected void submitt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {   con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into [Students] values ('" + ID.Text + "','" + FN.Text + "', '" + LN.Text + "', '" + Country1.Text + "', '" + gender.SelectedValue + "',  '" + email.Text + "', '" + passportNo.Text + "', '" + PlaceOfIssue.Text + "', '" + issue.Text + "',  '" + Expiry.Text + "', '" + VisaNo.Text + "', '" + VisaExpiry.Text + "', '" + EmiratesNo.Text + "', '" + EmiaratesExpiry.Text + "');", con);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Label1.Text = "Uploaded Successfully"; 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label2.Text = "Same data cannot be submitted again"; 
        }    
    }
}
```

and remove the following from code

```
public string Label1 { get; private set; }
public string Label2 { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`label1` and `label2` are declared as `object` type. There is no property `Text` for `object` so this error is coming. You may need to cast them.